# Google OAuth2 Bad Request

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, youtube-api, httpwebrequest, google-oauth

I am trying to write a YouTube app for windows phone, and I stumbled upon some problems on the authentication side. For some reason the following code is not working properly,

```
string url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?";
string postData = "code=" + str + "&client_id=*********.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=*******&grant_type=authorization_code";


HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);              

byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(postData);
httpWReq.Method = "POST";
httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";                

using (Stream stream =await httpWReq.GetRequestStreamAsync())
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

HttpWebResponse response =(HttpWebResponse)(await httpWReq.GetResponseAsync());

string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I am fairly new to `HttpWebRequest` so probably I missed something, although I am getting a response:

> Bad Request

To be specific it says that `grant_type` is missing although I am pretty sure that it is not, I did everything according to the documentation. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you're asking for the user's permissions, are you specifying `access_type=offline` in your request?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably fix it

```
            parameters.Append("code=" + str);
            parameters.Append("&client_id=*****.apps.googleusercontent.com");
            parameters.Append("&client_secret=*****");
            parameters.Append("&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto");
            parameters.Append("&grant_type=authorization_code");

            string p_params = parameters.ToString();
            byte[] p_data_params = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p_params);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            Stream dataStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            dataStream.Write(p_data_params, 0, p_data_params.Length);
            dataStream.Dispose();

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync();
            Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
            string result = readStream.ReadToEnd();
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: So basically I just missed the request.Accept ? Thanks, it works.